# how to get resultant rows using JOIN with LOGICAL from 5 tables fetching based on a primary key column

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I need to combine 4 table results of an Access tables which contains date of test with obtained score marks of a 4 different tests in each table. The information about the students such as name and department will be in the 5th table. All 5 tables will have *roll_number* as a primary key.

I just need to prepare a report in Excel with all received records with all respective fields. I would like to have it in quick time using either Excel vba or in other easy way if any. Please save me by your great help.

The score marks records will be store adequately once the finish their tests in each table as follows

```
tables Test1,Test2,Test3 & Test4 : roll_number, test1_date_of_test, mark1, mark2, totalmarks,result
```

And the table students will have the below fields

```
table students : roll_number, name, department.....
```

when I require the report, the excel sheet should have the below columns.

```
Report sql: roll_number, name, department, test1_dateoftest, test1_total, 
            test2_dateoftest, test2_total, test3_dateoftest, test3_total, 
            test4_dateoftest, test4_total
```

[Sample data from tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhFnx.png)

[retrieved results by using @parfait's query & desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2p83.png)

My sincere thanks for helping.

I did a sql query in Access below:

```sql
SELECT Students.Roll_number, 
Students.Sname, Students.Department, test1.Tot, test2.Tot, test3.Tot, test4.Tot, test1.DoT, test3.DoT, test2.DoT, test4.DoT
 FROM ((((Students 
LEFT JOIN test1 ON Students.Roll_number=test1.Roll_number) 
LEFT JOIN test2 ON Students.Roll_number=test2.Roll_number)
LEFT JOIN test3 ON Students.Roll_number=test3.Roll_number)
LEFT JOIN test4 ON Students.Roll_number=test4.Roll_number)
```

When I tried above JOIN query, I can get merged(students+test tables) results with any of test attended and non attended students result. But I need merged results with only any of test attended students list. As per image[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2p83.png) the **need result query with 5 rows only not full set of students table**, but now there is 8 rows as i seeded in students table

**THANK YOU for all & GREAT SUPPORT by @parfait & @melvinsmithsms**

Comment: *I did a sql query in Access below* and so what was wrong with your query?

Comment: its working good. Thanks a lot. If students table having 200 rows as constant and the test tables together having 15 rows only. So the resultant rows should have 15 only. But as per your query, I received 200 rows included attended students where as it will be great if I could receive only attended students with all fields [need reverse order result!!!]

Comment: Are you responding to my comment here or my proposed solution below? Please comment in appropriate places. Also, I still do not understand the problem with your (not my) posted query above especially as you claim: *its working good*.

Comment: Its working good with all students [included both attended and non attended list of students]. But expecting detailed list that who all are attended students only as of now.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, your problem requires a UNION (not a JOIN):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
(Select roll_number,test1_date_of_test as Date, test1_mark1 as Mark1, test1_mark2 as Mark2,test1_totalmarks as TotalMarks from test1
UNION
Select roll_number,test4_date_of_test as Date, test4_mark1 as Mark1, test4_mark2 as Mark2,test4_totalmarks as TotalMarks from test4)a
```

**Editing the answer based on comments**

If you are looking for the format mentioned in the question, you will have to edit the join condition:

```
SELECT 
             students.roll_number, students.name, students.depart, test1.tot, test2.tot, test3.tot, test4.tot, test1.dateoftest, test3.dateoftest,   test2.dateoftest, test4.dateoftest
FROM Students INNER JOIN test1 ON Students.roll_number=test1.roll_number INNER JOIN test2 ON
   Students.roll_number=test2.roll_number INNER JOIN test3 ON
   Students.roll_number=test3.roll_number INNER JOIN test4 ON
   Students.roll_number=test4.roll_number;
```

Comment: Great. But the result is not as expected. the result is not having segregation between 4 tests. I require the below format :-   student_roll_number, student_name, depart, test1_date, test2_date, test3_date, test4_date, test1_result test2_result, test3_result test4_result

Comment: roll_number,name,depart,test1_Date,test2_Date,test3_Date,test4_Date,test1_Mark1,test2_Mark1,test3_Mark1,test4_Mark1,test1_Mark2,test2_Mark2,test3_Mark2,test4_Mark2,test1_TotalMarks,test2_TotalMarks,test3_TotalMarks,test4_TotalMarks

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer based on your comments. Let me know if it works

Comment: Did all the students take all 4 tests? if that is not the case then the inner join might be removing these records

Comment: @Parfait  great full  thanks. Answered!!. The result was all records from students table combining all other test tables. so I had too many blank fields after students table columns [non attendees of students details also were included]. I just wondered to ask, is that possible to have only to list out test attended students only [students details should fetch into only those who ever filled data in test tables]. This will be the heavenly help. Thanks for you support

Comment: @melvinsitsms No sir!. student tables is a constant size, says about 200 rows. But the test tables will be vary, that is test table will receive record once the student attended the test only. Thanks for your swiftly response. Awesome.

Comment: You could use a where clause to restrict the data to students who ever filled data in test tables

Comment: help me. confused

Comment: I am not sure about access sql, but in sql server I would write something like: "where test1.toll_number is not null or test2.toll_number is not null or test3.toll_number is not null or test4.toll_number is not null"

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are bundling all `INNER JOIN` in nested pairings with *test3* as the originating data source. Consider starting with *students* and `LEFT JOIN` each *test* table in pairs to *Students*. And to keep students with at least one test add a `WHERE` clause to filter. Do note: parentheses are required for more than one join in Access SQL.

```sql
SELECT s.roll_number, 
       s.name, 
       s.depart, 
       test1.tot AS test1_total, 
       test2.tot AS test2_total, 
       test3.tot AS test3_total, 
       test4.tot AS test4_total, 
       test1.dateoftest AS test1_date, 
       test3.dateoftest AS test2_date, 
       test2.dateoftest AS test3_date, 
       test4.dateoftest AS test4_date 
FROM  ((((students s
          LEFT JOIN test1 ON s.roll_number = test1.roll_number)
          LEFT JOIN test2 ON s.roll_number = test2.roll_number)
          LEFT JOIN test3 ON s.roll_number = test3.roll_number)
          LEFT JOIN test4 ON s.roll_number = test4.roll_number)
 WHERE test1.roll_number IS NOT NULL
   AND test2.roll_number IS NOT NULL
   AND test3.roll_number IS NOT NULL
   AND test4.roll_number IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: That is very interesting! So the screenshot above *using @parfait's query* is this same `LEFT JOIN` query  without `WHERE` clauses?

Comment: Yes sir! the same result of without WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

SAMPLE DATA
[the samples for table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDzox.png)

```
SELECT s.roll_number, 
s.sname, 
s.department, 
test1.tot AS test1_total, 
test2.tot AS test2_total, 
test3.tot AS test3_total, 
test4.tot AS test4_total, 
test1.dot AS test1_date, 
test3.dot AS test2_date, 
test2.dot AS test3_date, 
test4.dot AS test4_date 
FROM  ((((students s
LEFT JOIN test1 ON s.roll_number = test1.roll_number)
LEFT JOIN test2 ON s.roll_number = test2.roll_number)
LEFT JOIN test3 ON s.roll_number = test3.roll_number)
LEFT JOIN test4 ON s.roll_number = test4.roll_number)
WHERE test1.roll_number IS NOT NULL
OR test2.roll_number IS NOT NULL
OR test3.roll_number IS NOT NULL
OR test4.roll_number IS NOT NULL;
```

this is the query to get the output as expected!!!
A **big thanks** to @Parfait

Comment: "AND" not gave the result as required in the screenshot. Also I specified that too -the answer is from you [Parfait] only. I don't know the process. Very sorry if I was wrong at any where.